# Background transparency

Tags: html, css

I want to make the header-menu background transparent so youtube video will be a little bit more visible [here](https://xlab.ge/)

This trick doesn't work

```
.masthead:not(.mixed-header) {
   background: rgba(247, 247, 47, 0.2)!important;
}
```

Any solution to show youtube video under the header-menu background?

Comment: better if you write a sample snippet

Comment: I'm note sure i understand what do you mean.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include the desired behavior**, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This seems to be fixed. Do you mind answering your question on how you did it?

Comment: This is a solution: .masthead:not(.mixed-header) {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)!important; 
}
#main-slideshow {
    overflow: visible !important;   
}

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Is this design you want ??

Then try this ..

```
.masthead:not(.mixed-header) {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)!important; 
}
#main-slideshow {
    overflow: visible !important;   
}
```